# My BenQ PD2700U does not work with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: display, hdmi, 20.04, monitor

I am trying to use a BenQ PD2700U with Ubuntu 20.04 and it doesn't work at all. It is connected to an HDMI port. I am new to Linux.

What might be the problem, and how can I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

my BenQ PD2700U works with Ubuntu 20.04 without doing anything special.
While I upgraded to 20.04 with the monitor connected and it just worked.
On top right of the screen go to settings and than screens to select ho to
exploit the new added sceen (mirror or joint).
best
Fred